# listview to tab

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-style-tabhost

I have 4tab on every tab I have listview, on selecting row(any row) I want to generate activity with 6tab,.

Comment: What? What are you trying to do?  What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: I agree with mayra, What are you trying to accomplish? OnClick of a listItem start and activity?

Comment: i have listview on selecting any row i want to start a new activity which have tabhost....

Answer (score 0):

@parkinson, Ok, so create an activity that has tabs. OnClick of a list item spawn a new intent and startActivity(new intent). BTW punctuation will help us understand what you are trying to say.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html
Also read this, It will help with spawning new activities.